# Don't reload VC1 when clicking back from CV2 - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I would like to navigate from VC1 (All Restaurant View) to VC2 (Restaurant Details View) and when ill press "Back Button" it shouldn't reload VC1 again.

How can I solve this?

```
func clickNameButtonCollectionView(sender: UIButton) {

        let restaurent_Id = ((self.allRecommendedRestaurent[sender.tag]  as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id") as AnyObject) as? Int

        let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResturantDetailsController") as! ResturantDetailsController
        obj.restaurent_ID = restaurent_Id!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
    }


@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Added:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.reloadJoinedData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        self.mainScrollView?.addSubview(refreshControl)

        self.appDel.apiManager.setCurrentViewController(vc: self)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        resturantTable.delegate = self
        resturantTable.dataSource = self
        resturantTable.bounces = false
        resturantcollection.delegate = self
        resturantcollection.dataSource = self
        resturantcollection.bounces = false
```

Comment: Are you using Tableview in VC1 to show all restaurants?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav UI View, Table View

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Can you upload code of VC1 @vanful

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav of course. Ill added it.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use block to perform any action after back button press. Follow below code

1) Create block in your `ResturantDetailsController`

```
var back_block : (() -> Void)? = nil
```

2) Update your back button action `backPressed`

```
@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let action = back_block {
        action()
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

3) Now in VC1 when you create `ResturantDetailsController` object.

```
    let obj = ResturantDetailsController.loadController()
    obj.back_block = {
        //reload Your TableView
    }
    obj.restaurent_ID = restaurent_Id!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
```

Comment: ill made evertything as you said. But still when ill get back from VC2 to VC1 its reloading the whole again.. did i miss understanding something maybe?

Comment: Is your data is upating after get back to VC1?

Comment: Yes it is updating again. The goal would be that it does not load again, since the data will not change when someone clicks on from an restaurant list to an restaurant and then back to the restaurant list.

Comment: If you’re calling api to update your restaurant data then call your api function in this block.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UITableView` in VC1 then reload it in `viewWillAppear` then you will get updated or this is you refresh your list

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.tableview.reloadData() 

}
```

Comment: currently my controller for that was as follow:
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.reloadJoinedData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        self.mainScrollView?.addSubview(refreshControl)
        
        self.appDel.apiManager.setCurrentViewController(vc: self)

Do I need to change the whole thing? Is their as well any other way? 
Maybe with .dismiss view etc?

Comment: Can you add this code in question, so i can check, and reloadJoinedData function what does?

Comment: The goal would be that it does not load again since the data will not change when someone clicks on from a restaurant list to a restaurant and then back to the restaurant list..

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code in `viewWillAppear` method in VC1 class:

```
 self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

It may helps you.Thank you.