# How to pass the value from ViewController B to ViewController A during dismiss ViewController using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

My scenario, I am trying to pass the value from `ViewController B` to `ViewController A` during dismiss the view controller. Here I used below code but I can’t able to get the value in `ViewController A`.

**ViewController B**

```
// protocol used for sending data back
protocol isAbleToReceiveData {
    func pass(data: String)  //data: string is an example parameter
}

// Making this a weak variable so that it won't create a strong reference cycle
var delegate: isAbleToReceiveData?

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        self.delegate?.pass(data: "someData") //call the func in the previous vc
}

@IBAction func Click_action(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        self.delegate?.pass(data: "someData") 
 }
```

**ViewController A**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, isAbleToReceiveData {

func pass(data: String) {
        print("USER: \(data)")
    }
}

// MARK: FromTouch Action
    @objc func fromTouchTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB")
        viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You need to make a Protocol in ViewController A, not in ViewController B...

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz He wanted to send data from VC_B to VC_A. So his delegates are correct.

Comment: you just need to add line `obj_VC_B. delegate = self`

Comment: Oh sorry, yes yes @dahiya_boy is right...

Comment: you can do this without using delegate, check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215641/dont-reload-vc1-when-clicking-back-from-cv2-swift/54216465#54216465)

Comment: Everything is right you missed assign delegate in your ViewController A while present ViewController B.

Comment: Can you explain by code? @ Nikunj Kumbhani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is right you missed assign delegate in your `ViewControllerA` while present `ViewControllerB`.

```
if let VC_B = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as? ViewControllerB{
    VC_B.delegate = self
    VC_B.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.present(VC_B, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note

> let viewController =
>   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
>   "ViewControllerB") as? ViewControllerB
>
> instad of
>
> let viewController = 
>   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
>   "ViewControllerB")

Comment: If I give that, I am getting Error: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'delegate'. @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @jackios Please check you ViewControllerB class name and you need to put this in MyViewController while present.

Comment: @jackios Please add your **ViewcontrollerB** Class name and code of present controller from **MyViewController** in question because you getting this error due to getting ViewController as a UIViewController while present but if you want to pass anything then you need to get Controller via Class name.

Comment: ViewcontrollerB.delegate = self if I add before present viewcontrollerB in Viewcontroller A, I am getting Error: Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'ViewcontrollerB' @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @jackios What is the Class name of your second ViewController here you write wrong code for a present that's why getting an error?

Comment: thank you buddy. working now. @ Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: Thank you for your answer. its working and more helpful. @ Nikunj Kumbhani

Answer (score 0):

First B should have a delegate variable that points to A. This means their must be a direct connection such as A is the parent of B.

Another easy solution if there is no direct connection between A and B is to use Notification Center. Where B generates an event and A Add observer to that event. You can follow this example: [Using Notification Center In Swift](https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewController A looks ok, but seems you did not set ViewController B's `delegate` variable, do it once you launch ViewController B, like so:

```
viewControllerA.present(viewControllerB, animated: true)
viewControllerB.delegate = viewControllerA // notice this line
```

Since you are within the instance of `viewControllerA`, replace `viewControllerA` with `self`

full delegation example below

```
protocol IsAbleToReceiveData: class {
    func pass(data: String)  //data: string is an example parameter
}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, IsAbleToReceiveData {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(launchAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Launch ViewController B", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func launchAction() {
        let viewController = ViewControllerB() // guard let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as? ViewControllerB else { return }
        viewController.delegate = self
        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }

    func pass(data: String) {
        print("Received Data: \(data)")
    }

}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: IsAbleToReceiveData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(exitAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Exit ViewController B", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func exitAction() {
        self.delegate?.pass(data: "Hello World!")
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func pass(data: String) {
        print("Received Data: \(data)")
    }

}
```

Comment: I am bit confused. I updated my question please check above. ViewController A to B then B to A movement happening in my app. ViewController B to A time I need to pass value from B to A.@AamirR

Comment: Check the update and sample project https://github.com/r-aamir/delegates_delegation

Comment: Thank you for your Awesome sample code answer. its working and more helpful.@ AamirR